# HMAC - SHA256 authentication via Postman

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, postman, hmac, postman-pre-request-script

I'm trying to simulate webhook POST request to my Rails app (which works well in a real workflow) by Postman. I found lots of examples but none of them work - I keep getting a 401 code. What I did is defined headers and `Pre-request Script` like below:

[image: postman headers]

JS as `Pre-request Script` based on [this docs](https://postman-quick-reference-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html?highlight=hmac#built-in-javascript-libraries)

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("hmac", CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(request.data, 'my_secret_string').toString(CryptoJS.digest));
```

And still I'm getting the 401 error.

The external API docs which I use to trigger webhook clearly state:

> Each webhook will be sent with the​ X-AQID-Signature​ header, which is created by hashing the request's payload with the HMAC method and SHA256 algorithm, using the shared secret as salt. This means that upon receiving a payload, you can verify its integrity by replicating the hashing method.

And like I said it works well in a real life workflow so I have an error in the postman implementation. What did I missed?

Comment: Did you see any errors? I think you do it right, the crypto part is not a problem, request payload might be.

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 except 401 I don't see any. My server logs shows me only `Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 103)` and that's it. Payload (I mean body) probably shouldn't matter.

Comment: sha256 produces same result with fixed inputs. So you can compare valid request with failed request to found out the differences.

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 exactly, so that's not the case - no difference what I put it there as long as it is a valid JSON.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to set any environment variable, you just have to add a header from your script. I did this in a very similar case:

```
var signBytes = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(pm.request.body.raw, 'YOUR_SECRET');
var signHex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(signBytes);
pm.request.headers.add({
    key: "HEADER_NAME",
    value: signHex
});
```

Answer (score 8):

If you need Base64 encoded value, then you can do it as follows:

```
CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(pm.request.body.raw, 'YOUR_SECRET').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```